How to deserialise from json to SearchResponse <Object> in Java
I've created a jsonResponse like this.
HttpResponse<String> httpResponse = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
String jsonResponse = httpResponse.body();

Now when I'm trying to deserialize it like this, it's giving me error that "Cannot resolve method 'deserialize' in 'Builder".
JacksonJsonpMapper jsonpMapper = new JacksonJsonpMapper();
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

SearchResponse.Builder<Product> searchResponseBuilder = new SearchResponse.Builder<>(AddonDocument.class);
searchResponseBuilder.deserialize(objectMapper.readTree(jsonResponse), jsonpMapper);

return searchResponseBuilder.build();

How to deserialize it then?
Deserialized searchresponse, but I'm getting this error.
